# Attribute values as input parameter in QGIS geopreocessing scripts

Tags: pyqgis, parameters

In QGIS geoprocessing scripts, I know how to connect an input parameter to a layer's attribute list. It would be like this:

```
##Input_layer=vector    
##Input_field_name=field Input_layer
```

But, is there any way to connect an input parameter to an attribute's unique value list? Maybe something like this:

```
##Input_field_value=value Input_field_name
```

Comment: What about my solution? Did it work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I thinked that could be helpful... Out of curiosity, which was your task?

Comment: I need to do some geoprocessing based on a field value from a layer loaded in the qgis project. The layers may have different names and fields, and the values will be different every time (so I can't use a selection parameter with a list of values).

Comment: My answer was correct with reference to your question because it permits to you doing some operations on the basis of a specific value stored in a field. Your explanation, instead, makes your question not clearer anymore. If you want more help, please edit your question adding more information and reporting what do you want to do with the parameters; otherwise, I can't help you anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could only set a `number` parameter and then directly connect it to you field:

```
##Input_layer=vector    
##Input_field_name=field Input_layer
##Value_for_the_field=number 10

from qgis.core import *
import processing
# Load the layer
layer = processing.getObject(Input_layer)

# Write the filter expression and set it
query = '%s = %s' % (Input_field_name, Value_for_the_field)
selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
for item in selection:
    # Do something
```